# Apache Kafka - Producer break on initTransaction

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api, spring-kafka

I'm testing an elementary transaction case, but it stays on producer.initTransaction();
Can any configuration be wrong?

```
public static void main(String[] argv) throws Exception {
    String topicName = "helloworldpartitioned";
    // Configure the Producer
    Properties configProperties = new Properties();
    configProperties.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092");
    configProperties.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
    configProperties.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
    configProperties.put(ProducerConfig.TRANSACTION_TIMEOUT_CONFIG, "1000");
    configProperties.put(ProducerConfig.CLIENT_ID_CONFIG, "test");
//      configProperties.put(ProducerConfig.ENABLE_IDEMPOTENCE_CONFIG, Boolean.TRUE);
    configProperties.put(ProducerConfig.TRANSACTIONAL_ID_CONFIG, PRODUCER_TRANSACTIONAL_ID);

    KafkaProducer<String, String> producer = new KafkaProducer<String, String>(configProperties);
    producer.initTransactions();
    producer.beginTransaction();
        String line = "TestMessage";
        System.out.println("Inizializzo la transazione");
        ProducerRecord<String, String> rec = new ProducerRecord<String, String>(topicName, line);
        producer.send(rec);
    // Thread.sleep(5000);
    producer.commitTransaction();
    producer.flush();
    producer.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to:

```
producer.initTransactions();
producer.beginTransaction();
    String line = "TestMessage";
    System.out.println("Inizializzo la transazione");
    ProducerRecord<String, String> rec = new ProducerRecord<String, String>(topicName, line);
    producer.send(rec);


// Thread.sleep(5000);
producer.commitTransaction();
producer.flush();
producer.close();
```

Comment: before it was so, but it always stays on the first line

Comment: In this example https://gist.github.com/apurvam/f94353a22d4cbe62a7d6abb0464f3891, he used `beginTransaction` before `producer.send(rec)`. But also he used `producer.sendOffsets(getUncommittedOffsets());` and then `producer.endTransaction();`. Maybe you can use something like this.

Comment: And I do not understand what do you mean in your comment?

Comment: i changed for security but the problem remains.

When enter in initTransaction, the process remain blocked without reaching beginTransaction()

Comment: Any console or exception log?

Comment: No, it seems to stay in the loop

Comment: your `producer.initTransactions();` code in the loop?

Comment: if yes take out it the loop and put it to before loop.

Comment: yes, exactly in TransactionalRequestResult.await() : line 50

Comment: can you put your full code, it is difficult to detect where is the problem.